# How to find out carrier's name in Android

Tags: android

How can I find out carrier's name in Android?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Never used it myself, but take a look at [TelephonyManager->getNetworkOperatorName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName()).

You could try something as simple as this:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: It does not work if you use Context.getService... should use the initalized context instead of the Class

Comment: TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Comment: The issue is that the resulting String is not the carrier written in Notification Bar.. For instance, MVNO are not showed.

Comment: Does this require a specific permission?

Comment: @pableu if I am using dual sim mobile means, how can I get the both carrier name?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka there is a manager.getSimOperatorName() method. It returns the same result in normal situation. but it may (and may not, i never tested it) return different result on roaming. If you're concern with roaming it worse to give it a shot.

Comment: verified on Android6&7, no need any permission!

Comment: is this code same when connected to WIFI?

Answer (score 26):

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: how to detect a operator from 10 digit phone number ?

Comment: Won't work for me on Brazil, comes empty. Only the "getSimOperatorName()" -> "Claro BR"

Comment: Network name is available if there is Network available along with user has selected sim for connecting to internet. Tested this on Android 7 dual sim phone and it returns name only in above condition. Even getSimOperator() behaves in same way atleast on my test phone.

Answer (score 12):

In case one needs the Carrier name of the Operator as shown on the Notifications bar as @Waza_Be asked. One could use the **getSimOperatorName** method instead, as several Telcos sublease their Network to other companies.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

Comment: it retursn primary sim operator fr dual sim ..how to get ops for both the sim

Comment: Hi @SrishtiRoy, it seems what you need is only supported on API level 22 and above. Check the comments on the accepted answer [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170425/get-operator-details-for-dual-sim-android-phone). Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

A Kotlin null safe implementation:

```kotlin
val operatorName = (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as? TelephonyManager)?.networkOperatorName ?: "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could try something LIKE THIS - Latest Working and improved code**

> IN JAVA

```
String getCarrierName() {
  try {
     TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) OneSignal.appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     // May throw even though it's not in noted in the Android docs.
     // Issue #427
     String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
     return "".equals(carrierName) ? null : carrierName;
  } catch(Throwable t) {
     t.printStackTrace();
     return null;
  }
}
```

> IN KOTLIN

```
 fun getCarrierName(): String? {
    return try {
        val manager =
            App.instance.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        // May throw even though it's not in noted in the Android docs.
        // Issue #427
        val carrierName = manager.networkOperatorName
        if ("" == carrierName) null else carrierName
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        t.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```