# How to identify dual sim carrier name in sdk level less than android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1

Tags: android, telephonymanager, dual-sim

I know from sdk level android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 we get subscriptionInfoList as subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
and by using this we will identify all the supported sim information.

I need getting the same in android lower versions. Anybody can help me ?

Comment: please see this link.i hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170425/get-operator-details-for-dual-sim-android-phone

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there are several native solutions.

For API >=17:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get information about all radio modules on device board
// and check what you need by calling #getCellIdentity.

final List<CellInfo> allCellInfo = manager.getAllCellInfo();
for (CellInfo cellInfo : allCellInfo) {
    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
        CellIdentityGsm cellIdentity = ((CellInfoGsm) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
        //TODO Use cellIdentity to check MCC/MNC code, for instance.
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
        CellIdentityWcdma cellIdentity = ((CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
        CellIdentityLte cellIdentity = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
        CellIdentityCdma cellIdentity = ((CellInfoCdma) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } 
}
```

In AndroidManifest add permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

To get network operator you can check mcc and mnc codes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code (general information).
- https://clients.txtnation.com/hc/en-us/articles/218719768-MCCMNC-mobile-country-code-and-mobile-network-code-list- (quite full and quite latest list of operators).

For newest devices you can use newest APIs.

For API >=22:

```
final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
final List<SubscriptionInfo> activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
    final CharSequence carrierName = subscriptionInfo.getCarrierName();
    final CharSequence displayName = subscriptionInfo.getDisplayName();
    final int mcc = subscriptionInfo.getMcc();
    final int mnc = subscriptionInfo.getMnc();
    final String subscriptionInfoNumber = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();
}
```

For API >=23. To just check if phone is dual/triple/many sim:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (manager.getPhoneCount() == 2) {
    // Dual sim
}
```

Comment: thank you.this is fine but i need to support my app from version 14. So this solution is not practical for such lower versions.

Comment: CellIdentity seems to reveal the MCC and MNC about the network you're currently on, but not the MCC and MNC of the carrier/country that the SIM card belongs to. I am currently using a Safaricom SIM card from Kenya, while in America. This card roams on T-Mobile, so I get the MCC/MNC values of 310 and 260, respectively. For many applications, this solution will not suffice.