# Get the network carrier name in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

How to access network carrier name such as Vodafone, T-Mobile etc in phonegap. Can anybody please tell me if its possible in phonegap for android, ios and windows mobile.

Comment: have not tried this with cordova/Phonegap but in iOS this is possible using core telephony framework

Comment: You would need to find or write a plugin for this.

Comment: Is it possible in android ??

Comment: the same question was answered 
[try it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468345/get-mobile-carrier-info-phonegap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to find out carrier's name in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838602/how-to-find-out-carriers-name-in-android)

I found this answer in so , look like there is currently no plugin for this however we need to make one ourselves

Comment: Did you ever write a plugin to accomplish this?

Comment: I am writing one, its not complete yet...will take some time

Comment: @Nav I really want to know more information about this plugin. The code is already on github? I can help you with the development. Also, do you know if Apple allows programatically access to the device's carrier?