# How can I get getNetworkOperatorName() with android 6.x

Tags: android, telephonymanager

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(tm != null)
    carrier = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

I just want to get network operator name which is called 'carrier'.
But always return "" with android 6 device. Is there any solution?

Comment: See comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838602/how-to-find-out-carriers-name-in-android#comment19751066_3838947

Comment: What Android 6 device? An emulator? There's no carrier in a emulator, probably

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> is this permission present or not in your code

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here is snippet, hope it helps you!
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get carrier name (Network Operator Name) 
String carrierName = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
String operatorName = tManager.getSimOperatorName(); //try this

// Get Phone model and manufacturer name 
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```