# Xamarin.Forms - Get cellphone provider for both Android and ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to get the cellphone provider for Android or iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retrieving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838602/how-to-find-out-carriers-name-in-android

Comment: I am looking for a C# / Xamarin.Forms solution.

Comment: Xamarin uses the native platform APIs, so you should be able to translate them into C# and implement them in a DependencyService

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Jason, you can use dependencyService to achieve it.

First of all, create a interface in PCL.

```
    public  interface ICellphoneProvider
    {
        string GetCellphoneProvider();
    }
```

Use it with following code

`string phoneProvider =DependencyService.Get<ICellphoneProvider>().GetCellphoneProvider();`

Achieve the `ICellphoneProvider` interface in Android .

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CellPhoneProviderService))]
namespace Xaminals.Droid
{
    class CellPhoneProviderService : ICellphoneProvider
    {
        public string GetCellphoneProvider()
        {
            Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager manager = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            string carrierName = manager.NetworkOperatorName;
            return carrierName;

        }
    }
}
```

Please add `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Achieve the `ICellphoneProvider` interface in iOS .

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CellPhoneProvideService))]
namespace Xaminals.iOS
{
    class CellPhoneProvideService : ICellphoneProvider
    {
        public string GetCellphoneProvider()
        {

            using (var info = new CTTelephonyNetworkInfo())
            {
                return info.SubscriberCellularProvider.CarrierName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If this reply is helpful, please mark it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.