# How to choose provider in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin

is there a possibility in Xamarin for both iOS and Android to perform a search of available providers (T-Mobile, AT&T....) and then to choose one? I couldn't find anything in the docs.
Thanks!

Searched docs but didn't find any helpful ressource.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511548/xamarin-forms-get-cellphone-provider-for-both-android-and-ios

Comment: Questions like this are going to have platform specific answers so it is usually best to ask two questions, however the answer for iOS is definitely not. Mobile carrier selection is handled through the device settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dependencyService` to search for the providers.

Firstly, create an interface in PCL:

```
public  interface ICellphoneProvider
{
    string GetCellphoneProvider();
}
```

Ahchieve the intherface in **Android**:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CellPhoneProviderService))]
namespace Xaminals.Droid
{
    class CellPhoneProviderService : ICellphoneProvider
    {
        public string GetCellphoneProvider()
        {
            Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager manager = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            string carrierName = manager.NetworkOperatorName;
            return carrierName;
        }
    }
}
```

Remain to add `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in AndroidManifest.xml

In **iOS**:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CellPhoneProvideService))]
namespace Xaminals.iOS
{
    class CellPhoneProvideService : ICellphoneProvider
    {
        public string GetCellphoneProvider()
        {

            using (var info = new CTTelephonyNetworkInfo())
            {
                return info.SubscriberCellularProvider.CarrierName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the DependencyService with the following code:

```
string phoneProvider =DependencyService.Get<ICellphoneProvider>().GetCellphoneProvider();
```